# Computed, print items on change without duplicate

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm trying to show items in a table every time the list of item changes. I've got a function and a computed but I'm not quiet sure if I'm doing it right.

```
Function(){
    Every time a new value comes in: changeList.push(item);
}
```

Then I have this computed

```
Computed:
    changedData: function(){
        return this.changeList;
    }
```

HTML

```
<tr v-for="change in changedData">
    <td>change.value</td>
<tr>
```

It does print out every item in the list when it is changed, but the thing is I don't want it to print out the items that already printed out, only new items.

EDIT: Found the problem (push function)

```
for(index in question.Answers){
    if(question.Answers[index].Selected === "selected" &&
     question.Answers[index].Value === savedQuestion.Value){
        this.myList.push({newValue: question.Answers[index].Value, oldValue: 
        savedQuestion.Value}); 
    }
   }
```

This will add all the questions with their value regardless if the list already contains the same question with the exact same values.

Comment: Hey you should check this example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LqKjMM?editors=1111 .It can certainly help you out.

Comment: Can you please post a codepen, also your computed property is redundant, since it's not doing any modification of the data.. no need to wrap `changeList` in a computed property.

Comment: Oh ok makes sense that I don't need computed. Also I think I've found the duplicate problem but not 100% sure how to solve it. The problem is in my push function where I add all the values I fetch into the list, regardless if the list already contains the items or not. Is there an easy way to check if a list contains specific objects, or should I make a new question for this?

Comment: It would be great if you can add your code.

Comment: Do you want me to make a new question or add it as an edit to this question?

Comment: You can edit the same question by just adding your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to achieve this you can check in the array if the object with same values is present or not.If not than only push the values.

Below is the updated code.

```
const search = (newVal,oldVal) => array.find(element => (element.newValue === newVal && element.oldValue === oldVal));

for(index in question.Answers){
  if(!search(question.Answers[index].Value,savedQuestion.Value))
    if(question.Answers[index].Selected === "selected" &&
     question.Answers[index].Value === savedQuestion.Value){
        this.myList.push({newValue: question.Answers[index].Value, oldValue: 
        savedQuestion.Value}); 
    }
   }
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but I discovered that I could just make an empty list every time i run the function, tempList.push(items) then at the end of the function outside the for-loop: this.myList = tempList

Comment: Yes that's for sure you can but i thought of this answer as you asked if there was any other way doing and may be you don't need to push all values again if they are present.

Answer (score 1):

In your code computed is actually not needed.Here is the basic example of adding dynamic values into the list at runtime.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LqKjMM?editors=1111

Template code =>

```
<script src="//vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>

<h1>Example of managing a Vue.js list</h1>

<div id="products">
  <vue-products></vue-products>
</div>

<script type="text/template" id='vue-products-template'>
  <div>
  <form v-on:submit.prevent="addProduct">
    <input type="text" v-model="productName">
    <input type="submit" value="Add"></input>
  </form>

  <ul>
    <li v-for="name in productNames">{{name}}</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</script>
```

Script code =>

```
Vue.component('vue-products', {
  template: '#vue-products-template',
  data: function() {
    return {
      productName: "",
      productNames: ['booze', 'tums', 'peas', 'short wave radio'],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addProduct: function() {
      this.productNames.push(this.productName)
      this.productName = ""
    }
  }
})

$(function() {
  new Vue({el: '#products', data: {}})
});
```